# .Net Entity Framework 4.0 Inheritance with MySQL and NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

Hy Everyone!

I'm using EF 4.0 with VS2010 and a MySQL as the database.
I have an abstract class (BaseEntity) and a derived class (ChildEntity). The BaseEntity has an Id property (which is the PK) and the ChildEntity has one more property (name). I'm using a Table-Per-Type strategy. (Btw, can I set the entity mapping? I know, that there is a tab for that, but I couldn't add new tables there for example...) My problem is that when I add a new ChildEntity to the context and save the context (SaveChanges method) I get a NullReferenceException.
The Code that I use:

```
using (var oc = new ModelContext())
{
   ChildEntity child = ChildEntity.CreateChildEntity(1, "Name");
   oc.AddToBaseEntities(child);                
   oc.SaveChanges();
}
```

And here is the exception stacktrace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=MySql.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at MySql.Data.Entity.InsertGenerator.GenerateReturningSql(DbModificationCommandTree tree, DbExpression returning)
       at MySql.Data.Entity.InsertGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree)
       at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
       at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree)
       at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree commandTree)
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(UpdateTranslator translator, Dictionary`2 identifierValues)
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
       at ConfigTool.Program.Main() in d:\dokumentumok\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConfigTool\ConfigTool\Program.cs:line 20
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

So, the error comes from the provider. I have an idea why it is thrown. When I added the inheritance to the model, it created a constraint, a PK-FK constraint between BaseEntity and ChildEntity. I think that the MySql provider is not fulfilling this constraint.
So can I do something about this or should I just forget using inheritance? Or maybe I'm missing something? And btw, how can I do a table-per-concrete-type strategy? (google it?)

I use the most current stable release of the provider and the server.

Thank you for your help.

Ps.: Sorry if something is messed up with the editing (or with my English), I'm new here.

Comment: Its a bit hard to diagnose from the code you have put up. WHat does the first parameter of the child entity represent where you have put in 1?

Comment: @AndyStannard
The constructor is generated. The first param is for the id, the second is for the name property. Here is the generated code:
`public static ChildEntity CreateChildEntity(global::System.Int32 id, global::System.String name)
{
  ChildEntity childEntity = new ChildEntity();
  childEntity.Id = id;
  childEntity.Name = name;
  return childEntity;
}`
I hope this helps.

Comment: Is the Id not created automatically, normally Id's for entities will be auto generated and you need to make sure that the entity model knows this in the configuration

Comment: Id I give is temporary. When I add it to the context with `AddToBaseEntites()` gets it's real ID. So it doesn't matter what I write to that param. It could be used for setting FK manually, but I use only Navigation Properties instead. When I created the Entity the FW automatically added the Id:Int32 field, set it a primary key and the values set to generate identity. So it's all automatic. If it's important, I can add a picture about the Model with the properties.